# WiFi issues on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, disconnect

[output of running the command sudo lshw -C network to fix WiFi issues on Ubuntu 22.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlDQU.jpg)

Comment: Please describe ***what*** is wrong with your WiFi? What do you want to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: It disconnects after sometime of turning my machine on and is unable to connect back to my network even after long search

Comment: Does `iwconfig` show power management on?

Comment: try turn off ``connectivity checking'' in gnome settings under privacy>connectivity

Comment: @Jeremy31, it shows off please,

Comment: @petep, I just turned it off

Comment: The results show it is disabled, any results for `rfkill list`

Comment: @Jeremy31, it is all no for Bluetooth and wireless LAN

Comment: I turned off connectivity as advised by @petep and ran sudo apt upgrade, so far, no issues, it is connecting and disconnecting as i so wish, i think the issue has been resolved 

Comment: Seems the issue isn't resolved yet, please assist me , anyone

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit the post to include results for the wireless script

Comment: I tried running the script on my CLI, getting the response "unable to establish SSL connection"...

Comment: @Jeremy31, here is the results from the script following this link https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XpYtCVKcsP/

Answer (score 1):

After so much toil, my hardware engineer diagnosed the issue to be a hardware problem, so i had my wireless card replaced, so far no challenge, all is going smoothly. thank you all for the assistance, God bless!